# Weighted graph similarity

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following problem. Consider an undirected biconnected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges ($n \leq m \leq n(n-1)/2$). The $m$ edges of the graph are then "populated" by integer weights from the set of integers $\{1,2,...,N\}$. I need to consider all possible permutations (with repetition) of these $N$ integers, which gives $N^m$ different graphs. For each of these graphs I need the determinant of a minor of the corresponding Laplacian matrix (doesn't matter which, all give the same result). By symmetry, several permutations will give the same result and the problem is to obtain the following:

1) The possible values of the determinant;

2) The multiplicity of each result, such that the sum of the multiplicities gives $N^m$.

Suggestions are highly appreciated!!